# Does “What do you don’t like to talk about?” sound alright?

Tags: grammaticality

I caught myself wondering if this question is right:

> What do you don’t like to talk about?

I’ve made some searches to get to know if this is grammatically allowed, however, I haven’t found any answer that can fulfill my question. Can you guys tell if it is right or not?

Comment: What do you not like to talk about?

Comment: Instead of - What do you not like to talk about?-, could I ask - What don´t you like to talk about?-

Comment: yes, that's okay. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since "don't" is a contraction of "do not," you have just written

> What do you do not like to talk about

which can be rearranged in normal sentence order as

> What you do do not like to talk about

Obviously, one of these do's should not be here.  So, change it either to

> What do you not like to talk about?

or

> What don't you like to talk about?